# Can Lenovo T520 / T530 series see Bluetooth LE devices?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, thinkpad, bluetooth-le

Thinkpad T520 T530 have an integrated Bluetooth device, but I don't manage to see Bluetooth "LE" (Low Energy) beacon devices.

For example I tried with [Nirsoft BluetoothViewer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetooth_viewer.html) but I don't see the BT LE devices.

(Note: I'm *not* looking for a software, but just to know if these Thinkpads support BT LE.)

Comment: It depends on the BT version it cames with: https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/bluetooth-versions and https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/bluetooth-le

Comment: Thanks @ChanganAuto. I think BT LE comes with BT 4 - how to know if T520 / 530 have BT 4?

Comment: That's up to you to find out if you already have the machine(s). Otherwise check detailed hardware specifications from official sources.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I don't see where on Windows I can find this information...

Comment: You can check any hardware part at device manager and, even if the "human readable" name doesn't give any indication, the VID&PID certainly does, googling with those codes is easy. Then a properly up-to-date Windows - nowadays this means Windows 10 or newer only (so, Windows 10 because there's no way for that ancient machines to support Windows 11) - or any mainstream Linux distro should support all the available BT features allowed by its hardware version.

Comment: Thanks @ChanganAuto I didn't know the VID&PID trick!